# Can I have a different dictionary for flyspell in different headings?

Tags: org-mode, flyspell, spell-checking

I have an org-mode file where I use different languages. I was hoping to be able to have flyspell checking them. Something like:

```
* Title 1 
:PROPERTIES:
:Language: Italian
:END:
This is italian text spell checked.

* Title 2
:PROPERTIES:
:Language: American 
:END:
This is english text spell checked.
```

Comment: Have you made any progress on that?